# Saving plot output object in IPython for later plotting

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I'm using IPython with inline graphics to do some plots, and I'm wondering how I could bind the output of a plot command

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57090>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57310>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57510>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57690>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57810>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57990>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x11ac57b10>,
 ....
 ....
]
```

object array to a variable, so I could then plot it later?

Thanks!  Jeff

Comment: This functionality is more-or-less on the near term road map.  The current best-practice is to save the _code_ you used to generate the figure (which is fully in line with reproducible computing).  If you find your self writing the some set of plotting commands over and over, you should write a helper function: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#coding-styles

Comment: And to be clear, what you have there is the artists added, not the full figure.  Such objects are not directly re-usable (as they are 'bound' to the `Axes` object that they are currently shown in)